# Generar QR con PhP, mysql, ajax

Tags: javascript

me gustaria que me apoyasen con el siguiente codigo que presentare, les explico, estoy haciendo un sistema de facturación usando PHP, AJAX Y MySQL, pero quiero generar el codigo QR basandose en los datos de la factura, pero de los diferentes codigos que he montado, ninguno me quiere dar y me gustaria que me apoyasen o me den las pistas para lograr tal fin. Les remito lo que llevo hasta ahora:

```
GenerarQR.php

    <?php   
    
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
        //*Conexion a base de datos *//
    
        $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "contrumeca"); 
    
        $codigosqr = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT codproducto, nombre_producto, margen_utilidad, unidad_manejo, descripcion, proveedor, precio, existencia, tipo_producto, imagen FROM producto ORDER BY codproducto DESC LIMIT 1");
        
        $response = array();   
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    
        //*Generando el codigo QR *//
        require 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
    
        $directorio = '';
    
        //*Si no existe la carpeta *//
    
        $filename = $directorio.'test.png';   
        
        //*El bucle y el envio del correo *//
    
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($codigosqr))
    
       {    
        $response = array();              
                            
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_noadministradores WHERE correo = '$correo'";
        
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            if($count>0) 
            {
    
               $filename = $directorio. "".$row['codproducto'].'.png';
    
               $archivo = $filename;  
              
               $contenido = "Identificador: {$row['codproducto']}, {$row['nombre_producto']}, Por:{$row['unidad_manejo']}, {$row['descripcion']}, {$row['precio']}, {$row['tipo_producto']}";
                  
               QRCode::png($contenido, $filename);      
                            
               require 'PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';
            
               $mail = new PHPMailer();     
                  
               $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;   
               $mail->isSMTP();   
               $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";  
               $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
               $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
               $mail->Username = '';
               $mail->Password = '';
               $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
               $mail->Port = 587;                                         
                   
               $mail->setFrom('', '');
               $mail->addAddress($correo);             
               $mail->addAttachment($archivo);    
                                                  
               $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
               $mail->Subject = 'Codigo QR generado';
               $mail->Body    = "<p>Estimado/a, {$row['nombre']}
               <br>
               <p>Reciba un cordial saludo desde Construcciones Metalurgicas. A traves de la presente es para informarle que el Codigo QR ha sido generado de manera exitosa desde la aplicación oficial de Contrumeca C.A, el cual se le ha sido adjuntado en formato PNG</p>
               
               <p>Le invitamos a escanear el codigo a traves del Lector Oficial de la aplicación oficial, para asi corroborar que los datos del mismo coincidan con lo que se registro</p>
               
               <p>Sin nada mas a que hacer referencia</p>
               <br>
               <p>Atentamente.</p>
               
               <p>Ing</p>
               
               <p>Analista de Ventas Contrumeca C.A</p>
               <br>
               <br>
               <br>
               <br>
               <p>Este mensaje solo debio ser recibido por el destinatario arriba indicado y puede contener informacion privilegiada o confidencial. Si usted lo ha recibido por error, le agradecemos notificarlo de inmediato a: contrumeca.ca@gmail.com . Gracias</p>";       
                                  
                           
               if(!$mail->send()) {
         
                  $response["success"] = true;
                   $response["message"] = "success";
               } else {
                   $response["success"] = true;
                   $response["message"] = "success";
               }
         
               
            
            
         } 
         
          
           }
           echo json_encode($response);    
              
    }
        
      ?>
```

Claro, el codigo aun se encuentra en construcción, sigo validando pero mi duda es que como estoy usando AJAX, no se como declarar la función para que cuando le de procesar venta y me genere el PDF de la factura, lo cual mi sistema esta haciendo, a a su vez genere el QR, lo guarde en el directorio, lo envie al correo y lo muestre en la factura, les remito la parte de mi codigo de javascript donde hago referencia a tal cosa.

```
//PROCESAR LA FACTURA
$('#btn_facturar_venta').click(function(e) 
{

e.preventDefault();

var rows = $('#detalle_venta tr').length;
if(rows > 0) 
{


var action = 'procesarVenta';
var codcliente = $('#idcliente').val();

$.ajax({

url: 'ajax.php',
type: "POST",
async: true,
data: {action: action, codcliente: codcliente},

success: function(response) 
{

if(response != 'error') 
{
var info = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(info);
generarPDF(info.codcliente, info.nofactura);
location.reload();
    

}else
{

console.log('no data');

}


},

error: function(error) 
{

}



});

}


});

function generarQR(){}
```

Por favor, estare muy agradecida si me pueden apoyar en como generar el QR de la factura y que lo imprima en la factura, ya que esto es para mi tesis de grado y mi sistema esta casi 90% listo y me queda poco tiempo. Gracias!!!

Comment: Hola @GeorginaMontilla, exactamente que información debe contener el código QR, porque tal y como lo explicas no entiendo que debe contener.

Comment: El codigo QR solo traera la información de la factura, lo que no es como ponerlo en el ajax y es el proceso para que lo haga cuando le de al boton de facturar.

Comment: Hola @GeorginaMontilla, dos cosas, primero edita el código de la pregunta y elimina el password del email y cámbialo en gmail antes de que lo pille alguien, que hay gente para todo. Por otro lado, el QR con la librería phpqrcode, lo generas correctamente ```QRcode::png('datos', 'fichero.png');```lo único que tienes que comprobar es que el fichero y la ruta sea la correcta para después recuperarlo. Yo lo que haría es pasarle al ajax el número de factura o un campo que la identifique como valor único y llamar así al fichero que genera el qr.

Comment: Entonces antes del ```generarPDF(info.codcliente, info.nofactura);``` lo generas y como ya les estás pasando el número de factura a esa función, ahí recuperas el fichero y lo metes en el pdf. O lo puedes generar directamente en esa función, lo que veas más cómodo para ti.

Comment: Hola, como estas? Yo ya tengo la libreria de PHPQRCode, eso esta más que listo, mi duda es que como programar el AJAX para que me genere el QR, porque de verdad no se, no se, y de lo poquito que hay en internet y he recolectado, no me ayuda para nada, por eso estoy por este foro.

Comment: Si ya generas el código **QR** en PHP, porque no lo devuelves a tu response al igual que envíes un mensaje *success*, puedes hacer algo como: ```$response["qr_code"] = 'pasas_el_qr';``` y ya lo tendrías en tu **AJAX**.